# Data label is not shown in xy scatter chart

Tags: excel, vba, label, excel-charts

I have tried to create an XY scatter chart to display an explosive charge map with given XY coordinates of each drilled hole. Then I tried to label each hole number with VBA code below;

```
Sub Create_Charge_Map()

Dim ochartObj As ChartObject
Dim oChart As Chart

Worksheets("Charge_Map").Select

Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=10, Left:=325, Width:=600, Height:=300)
Set oChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
oChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

'set a source data for each hole to be displayed with their xy coordinations'

```
oChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C14:D4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("J14:J4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("M14:M4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("P14:P4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("S14:S4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("V14:V4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("Y14:Y4500")
oChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Range("C14:D4500")
```

'Set a scale of X and Y axes'

```
oChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
oChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("T8").Value
oChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("T9").Value
oChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
oChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("S8").Value
oChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("S9").Value
```

'Labelling the hole number for each hole'

```
Dim HoleDataSeries As Series
Dim SingleCell As Range
Dim HoleList As Range
Dim HoleCounter As Integer
Dim FontSize As Range
HoleCounter = 1

Set FontSize = Range("AG2")
Set HoleList = Range("B14:B4500") 

Set HoleDataSeries = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
HoleDataSeries.HasDataLabels = True
For Each SingleCell In HoleList
HoleDataSeries.Points(HoleCounter).DataLabel.Text = SingleCell.Value
HoleCounter = HoleCounter + 1
Next SingleCell

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
    .Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
    .Orientation = xlHorizontal
    .Font.Size = FontSize
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
End Sub
```

But it appears to miss hole number 34 (The data I used has 345 holes in total; every hole is shown but a hole 34).

I do not know what I did wrong.

Comment: Hi, could you share your data sheet. I would like to try this out. Also can you check the count of Data Labels after chart is generated, like  *MsgBox ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Count*

Comment: There's doesn't seem to be anything in your code which would resolve to "34", so likely it's something off in your source data.

Comment: @Tim Williams, Yeah it seems to be nothing wrong with my code, but even in my data, I could not find anything odd.

Comment: @Charlie, Hey I'm new to this community do you know how to share a file?

Comment: You can upload to google/one drive/whatever and share a link

Comment: Found the problem. I had to adjust X and Y ranges by adjusting their maximum to be more than their actual maximum in the dataset. For example, if the value of my X data is 750000 then the range of the X-axis has to be more than 750000 so it can still visualise my all X data and so does for Y. But Thanks for all your ideas and shares.